# Why getBoundingClientRect().top returns 0 after each alternative pixel scroll?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getboundingclientrect

I want my `.row-navigation` row to be `position-fixed` when scrolled. So i used `window.onscroll` to listen to the scroll event and assign the class `.sticky` , to `.row-navgation` row , when scrolled. In the process `getBoundingClientRect().top` is used.

**The unexpected behaviour:**
When the scroll event takes places then `getBoundingClientRect().top` returns `0` with each alternate pixel scroll.
**As a result** The `.row-navigation`row flickers when scrolled

**Check this on codepen** https://codepen.io/neel111/pen/NVaEyB

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-welcome"></div>
  <div class="row-navigation"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.row-welcome {
  height: 34px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.row-navigation {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.row-navigation.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var rowNavigation = document.querySelector('.row-navigation');
    var nextDomElement = rowNavigation.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

    console.log(rowNavigation.getBoundingClientRect().top, rowNavigation.getBoundingClientRect().right, rowNavigation.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);  

    if (0 > rowNavigation.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
      rowNavigation.classList.add('sticky');
    } else {
      rowNavigation.classList.remove('sticky');
    }
}
```

How to fix the unexpected behaviour of `getBoundingClientRect().top`?

Comment: You're assigning `top:0` yourself using the `sticky` class.

Comment: @Geert-Jan Oh shit! That's a silly and naive mistake. I presume the `top:0` is necessary  in the `sticky` class. How can i make it work smoothly?

Comment: If you want to check if the window has scrolled at all use `window.scrollY` instead in your condition